# Manga where the female lead is reincarnated in another world by her new father, who was a demon or something

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

The manga's main character is female. She was reincarnated by her new dad in the world who was a demon or something. The main character has a problem with her soul, because it keeps her attached to her original world and it hurts her mind in the new one. Her new dad fixes it when she sleeps, but can’t completely make her forget about her old life. In this new life, she tries to be a cute daughter but does not really know how and her dad is pretty emotionless the majority of the time.

Plot point:
Her dad killed all the other kids except her and her brother, whom he does not claim and hates. He’s locked in a cage in a dungeon and ends getting his tongue cut off, so he can’t cast spells . The main character learns that she has healing powers and heals him and starts spending time with him a lot.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: It’s full color but I don’t remember the female leads hair I think her brothers hair is black and her father is white

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[The Adorable Princess of Doom](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-adorable-princess-of-doom)***...?

> Eun Lee has had an eventful day. First, she won the lottery. Then, she was summoned to a mystical realm by the Demon King, Kaon Mahana Lord Moon Blood Rain, and was newly named Rue, princess of the demon realm. Eun demands to be returned to her original world so she can collect her winnings, but Kaon wonders if she has something to do with his late lover’s will. Eun surprises herself by adjusting to her new and unfamiliar life, but will she ever truly let go of her past and find happiness here?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "The Adorable Princess of Doom."]

As indicated in the synopsis above, a Korean woman is summoned to another world by a (white-haired) Demon King, and named as princess of the demon world. Her new body is that of a little girl, about four or five years old.

The Demon King shows no affection towards her outwardly, but she's well taken care of by his servants, given spell books to study, and the Demon King uses magic on her while she's sleeping to help heal her emotional wounds from her past life. It's stated in chapter 11 that her soul still has a connection to her past life.

In chapter 18, she goes down to a dungeon in the lower levels of the Demon King's palace, and finds a boy resembling the Demon King imprisoned within a giant bird cage. The boy can only speak with telepathy, since his tongue was cut off, so she heals him with a kiss, enabling him to speak normally again.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/the-adorable-princess-of-doom/info).

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Akiramio - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Comment: @Akiramio - Shortly after I posted my previous comment, someone upvoted this answer. I don't know if that was you, but if it was, upvoting an answer isn't the same thing as marking it as accepted. To formally accept an answer, you need to click on the grey check mark that's just below the upvote and downvote buttons. It should turn from grey to green if you click on it. It's totally up to you whether you want to do that or not, but if this answer is correct, then it would be appreciated.